# Convergence of random walk in $R^2$ to the Brownian motion on circle

Tags: convergence, central-limit-theorem, random-walk, brownian-motion

We know that the random walk generated in $R^1$ can converge weakly in distribution to the Brownian motion in $R^1$. Could anybody provide a mathematical proof, how a random walk generated in $R^2$ can converge in distribution to the standard Brownian motion on a circle using an appropriate mapping?

Comment: I don't see any sense in which a brownian motion, *qua* stochastic process, can be transformed into a brownian motion on the circle, because any transformation would necessarily destroy the iid property of the increments.

Comment: It seems that this idea is being used. For example [here](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~acamer4/brownianposter.pdf)

Comment: That post is *nothing* like what you are asking!

Answer (score 1):

This is rather sophisticated and not a one-line proof one could present here. Anyway, here is some (my) intuition. The circle has a Lie-group structure and therefore one can in a natural way talk about random walks on a circle. Then mimicing the strategy of Donskers invariance theorem on the real line, i.e. interplolate, rescale etc, you will be able to prove that the random walk will converge weakly to some Markov process whose generator is the Laplace-Beltrami operator on the circle, i.e. you end up with Brownian motion on the circle.
Here is a classical reference:
https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/25049879.pdf

Comment: could you please add the reference for your link in case it dies in the future? Thanks!

Comment: Stroock, Varadhan: Limit Theorems for Random Walks on Lie Groups